# Smart way to replace sublist with one element in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, list, haskell

I have defined 2 types in Haskell - `Trip` and `Tour`. Trip consists of `direction`, `distance` and `price`. The Tour is a list of Trips.

```
type Trip = (String, Integer, Float)
type Tour = [Trip]

trip1 :: Trip
trip1 = ("NY", 50, 100)
trip2 :: Trip
trip2 = ("Paris", 150, 100)
trip3 :: Trip
trip3 = ("London", 60, 100)
...
...
tripN :: Trip
tripN = ("Rome", 90, 100)

tour :: Tour
tour = [trip1, trip2, trip3,..., tripN]
```

The trips may have duplicates. What I want to accomplish here is to have function that takes one `Tour`, **`from`** destination, **`to`** destination and a `Trip` and the function replaces **all** the Trip sequences between the **`from`** and **`to`** destinations with the `Trip`, *starting right after the **`from`***, and get the changed `Tour`.

Here is an example with the tour defined above:

```
shortenTour :: Tour -> String -> String -> Trip -> Tour
shortenTour tour "NY" "London" ("NY-London", 260, 200)
```

so the beginning of the new Tour should be something like this:

```
[("NY", 50, 100), ("NY-London", 260, 200), ... , ("Rome", 90, 100)]
```

If this sequence "NY" - .. - "London" is met anywhere else in the `Tour` it should be changed with the new `Trip`.

If there are two or more trips with the same **`from`** destination (ex. "NY") before meeting the **`to`** destination the first **`from`** should be taken. Ex: (the `distance` and `price` don't get in use so I am replacing them with _ )

```
shortenTour [("DC", _, _), ("NY", _, _), ("NY", _, _), ("Sofia", _, _), ("London", _, _)] "NY" "London" ("NY-London", 260, 200)
```

should return

```
[("DC", _, _), ("NY", _, _), ("NY-London", 260, 200)]
```

All the solutions that came up to me are long and bit ugly but I believe there is a smart and short (one or two rows of code) way to accomplish this by using list comprehensions but still cannot figure it out. So any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you do `data Trip = Trip { tripDirection :: String, tripDistance :: Double, tripPrice :: Int }`? This way it explains itself. `Type`def-ing tuples is confusing and makes many things more complicated, because you can't use record syntax.

Comment: The thing you said makes sense but it's not me who decide whether to use type or data or tuples. It is the given in the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Haskell is very rough these days, but what you're looking for is:

- the shortest prefix ending in `from` -- you can get this using
  `takeWhile`;
- the longest suffix starting with `to`, but containing no
  other `to` -- you can get this using `tails` with a filter.

Then you can join the prefix, your shortcut, and the (tail of the) suffix, to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the handout :) I'm not sure if I can use tails for the task (probably with only using the Prelude module), but I get the basic idea. I'll try to come up with some workaround.